# Set margin in printing GW-BASIC

Tags: printing, dos, gw-basic

I'm using GW-BASIC language and I need the output to be printed at the center of the page, right now it starts from the top left of the A4 size page, can I tried to set the margin using printer preference but there is no such option.

Can anyone tell me how to set it to print to the center of the page?

Answer (score 1):

GW-BASIC just sends the text (the bytes actually) printed with `LPRINT` to the DOS `LPT1:` device.  To center text on a page one has to take into account the size of the paper, the printed character sizes and the line spacing.

The default for most printers[^1] is a monospace font, i.e. all characters have the same width, and that there are ten characters per inch (10 CPI) and the line spacing is set to ten lines per inch.[^2]  For Letter sized paper this is max. 66 lines on a page.  A4 paper is a bit narrower than Letter but still wide enough to print the 80 characters at 10 CPI.  And it's a bit longer than 11 inch, so you can fit some more lines onto a single page.

So the simple, mostly printer model independend answer is to skip as many lines by printing just line endings to reach the middle line, and then print as many spaces as needed to center the text in that line.

The following example prints a ”ruler” at the top to see how wide 80 characters actually are printed.

Setting the `WIDTH` isn't really necessary with the default value of 80, but is important if the lines printed are longer, because otherwise GW-BASIC inserts a carriage return and line feed after 80 bytes that didn't contain a line ending character.  So even if the printer has a pitch of 12 CPI and could fit 96 charaters into 8 inch, GW-BASIC would break the lines after 80 characters.

```
10 LL=80 'Line length.
20 LC=66 'Line count.
30 WIDTH"lpt1:",LL 'Default is 80. 255 for disabling automatic CR+LF.
40 :
50 REM Print a "ruler".
60 FOR I=1 TO LL\10:LPRINT SPACE$(9);MID$(STR$(I),2);:NEXT
70 FOR I=1 TO LL:LPRINT MID$(STR$(I MOD 10),2);:NEXT
80 :
90 T$="Centered on page."
100 :
110 N=(LC-2)\2 'Number of lines to the center. -2 because of the ruler lines.
120 IF N>0 THEN FOR I=1 TO N:LPRINT"":NEXT 'Skip N lines.
130 LPRINT TAB((LL-LEN(T$))\2);T$
```

Resulting in a page looking like this:

---

[image: Printout on matrix printer.]

---

To advance to the top of the next page quickly print a form feed character (`LPRINT CHR$(12);`).

---

[^1]: Printers that directly print text and don't need a specially formatted data stream like PostScript printers for instance.  But as the question stated that text appears at the top left of the page, the printer in question seems to be not a PostScript printer.

[^2]: On some printers those settings can be changed on the printer via buttons or DIP switches.  Common options include changing between 10 CPI (Pica) and 12 CPI (Elite) or ”condensed” (17.5 or 20 DPI) mode, to fit more text per line.

Answer (score 0):

No way for me to be sure what the x and y need to be for your specific message on an A4 sized paper, but using the LOCATE statement to move the cursor would be the easiest way.

Likely take trial and error to get your message to be perfectly centered on your particular display.

Quick Google got me this : [GW-BASIC User's Guide - LOCATE Statement](http://www.antonis.de/qbebooks/gwbasman/locate.html)

From the site:

> Syntax:
>
> ```
> LOCATE [row][,[col][,[cursor][,[start] [,stop]]]]
> ```
>
> Comments:
>
> **row** is the screen line number, a numeric expression within the range of 1 to 25.
>
> **col** is the screen column number, a numeric expression within the range of 1 to 40, or 1 to 80, depending upon screen width.
>
> **cursor** is a Boolean value indicating whether the cursor is visible; zero is off, nonzero is on.
>
> **start** is the cursor start scan line, a numeric expression within the range of 0 to 31.
>
> **stop** is the cursor stop scan line, a numeric expression within the range of 0 to 31.

Only the first two arguments are really necessary for a simple movement of the cursor, something like:

```
10 LOCATE 4,20
20 PRINT "YOUR TITLE HERE"
```

The above would move the cursor to the 4th row and 20th column then print "YOUR TITLE HERE".

Comment: Yeah. I know it is over a month old, but I figured it might help if anyone came back looking...

Comment: It would be useful if you added the relevant code to your answer. That way, if the link stops working, your answer may still help future visitors.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  LOCATE is for screen output, it can't be used for text that goes to the line printer.